# Access SQL group by name and then set values in horizontal from month1 to month12

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot, crosstab

I have a Table that has (names, money, date) And I would like to get the (name, money of month 1, money of month 2 and so on to month12)

How to do it?

I know how to extract the month from the date;

Comment: Do you have multiple entries for each month for any one name?  And would that mean you want those values summed, or just the most recent value?  Do you have an example of the code you've written so far?

Comment: i've already done it with 2 querys, see answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First query:
name, iif(month(date) = 1, money, 0) AS m1, and so on up to m12

Second query:
name, sum(m1) AS mo1, and so on up to mo12
group by name

Limitations: only one insert per month and the query must have an year filter that selects ONLY 1 YEAR.

Comment: This is *not* how you do it, see Philippe's and mine answers.

Comment: As has been said previously, pivots are a far better and scalable option

Answer (score 0):

you might want to build a pivot table, using the month function to generate the month value for each of your dates. You'll then be able to use this month value as a column in your pivot table.

Be careful: values for same months in different years will be aggregated, unless you expressely filter your data for a specific year

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called crosstab query in msaccess parlance (and PIVOT in bigger systems).

Here's [Allen Brown](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html#Example)'s nice write up with a lot of attention to detail.